# how to use SPeL to evalute to a function (think lambda)

Tags: java, spring, lambda, spring-el

Here is the code I would like to achieve in its simplest form:

```
@Autowired
private Validator validator:

private <T> Function<Object,Set<ConstraintViolation<T>>> validate = validator::validate;
```

Ideally, I want this (though, this doesn't work).

```
@Value("#{validator::validate}")
private <T> Function<Object,Set<ConstraintViolation<T>>> validate;
```

Just using SPeL to directly wire it in

Comment: Read twice, didn't caught your idea.

Comment: SpEL doesn't support Lambdas. Not sure if it will...

Comment: SpEL is not Java; it's ...er SpEL.